# How to pass a complex lambda function to gremlin server by using Java API?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm trying to traverse the graph with an interval. Each edge has a property("interval") storing the intervals. I'm using `withSack` to propagate the intersections of the intervals to the next step. If there's no intersection the traversal should stop.

For example:

```
V1          e1         V2         e2          V3         e3          V4

O----------------------O----------------------O----------------------O
^
    [[1,3],[5,7]]              [[4,6]]                [[7,9]]
     e1.interval             e2.interval            e3.interval
```

If I start traversal from V1 with interval [2,8], I want it to return

```
V1: [[2,3],[5,7]]
V2: [[5,6]]
```

Notice that V3 and V4 is not included since the intersected interval on e2 stops at 6.

I'm using Tinkerpop Java API and for this purpose, I defined a method that returns the intersections of the intervals and tried to use `withSack(Lambda.biFunction(...))`. The function has while loop with curly braces(`{}`) and I think it causes a problem on the gremlin server's script engine. The exception I'm getting is this:

```
Script28.groovy: 1: expecting '}', found 'return' @ line 1, column 520.
   get(j).get(1)) i++; else j++;}return int
```

I'm passing the function as a string to `(Lambda.biFunction(...))` like this:

```
"x, y -> " +
"List<List<Long>> intersections = new ArrayList();" +
"if (x.isEmpty() || y.isEmpty()) return new ArrayList<>();" +
"int i = 0, j = 0;" +
"while (i < x.size() && j < y.size()) {" +
"long low = Math.max(x.get(i).get(0), y.get(j).get(0));" +
"long high = Math.min(x.get(i).get(1), y.get(j).get(1));" +
"if (low <= high) intersections.add(Arrays.asList(low, high));" +
"if (x.get(i).get(1) < y.get(j).get(1)) i++; else j++;" +
"}" +
"return intersections;";
```

For the readability I'm also putting the original function:

```
public List<List<Long>> intersections(List<List<Long>> x, List<List<Long>> y) {
    List<List<Long>> intersections = new ArrayList();

    if (x.isEmpty() || y.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (i < x.size() && j < y.size()) {
        long low = Math.max(x.get(i).get(0), y.get(j).get(0));
        long high = Math.min(x.get(i).get(1), y.get(j).get(1));

        if (low <= high) {
            intersections.add(Arrays.asList(low, high));
        }

        if (x.get(i).get(1) < y.get(j).get(1)) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }

    return intersections;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to pass a complex lambda function like this to gremlin server?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string of your lambda needs to match a [Groovy closure form](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html). For your multiline and multi-argument script you need to wrap some curly braces around it:

```
withSack(Lambda.biFunction(
"{ x, y -> " +
"  intersections = []\n" +
"  if (x.isEmpty() || y.isEmpty()) return []\n" +
"  i = 0\n" +
"  j = 0\n" +
"  while (i < x.size() && j < y.size()) {\n" +
"    def low = Math.max(x[i][0], y[j][0])\n" +
"    def high = Math.min(x[i][1], y[j][1])\n" +
"    if (low <= high) intersections.add(Arrays.asList(low, high))\n" +
"    if (x[i][1] < y[j][1]) i++; else j++\n" +
"  }\n" +
"  return intersections\n" +
"}"))
```

I also converted your Java to Groovy (hopefully correctly) which ends up being a little more succinct but that part should be unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got the same exception: ```expecting '}', found 'if' @ line 1, column 158. x, y ->   intersections = []  if (x.isEm``` . 
However, I've written the same function to a groovy script file which is initialized by ```ScriptFileGremlinPlugin``` on server startup. Then I was able to call the function in my query.

Comment: oh...i got rid of the semi-colons but didn't add line feeds. updated answer. maybe that will fix it. it's something simple like that. just a syntax error in the groovy evaluation.